# How can I set the datasource in mybatis-config.xml when using springboot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

Spring Boot can create the datasource when I config the datasource in application.properties. As follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I also can set a mybatis-config file in `application.properties`. like:

```
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

As we all know, the `mybatis-config.xml` can config the datasource,too.
So what if I don't set the datasource in `application.properties`,but only set the datasource in `mybatis-config.xml`?

I tried, I removed the datasource configuration in `application.properties`, and set the datasource in mybatis-config.xml. But it didn't work.

How can I set the datasource in mybatis-config.xml when using springboot?

Answer (score 1):

You should put database properties in spring-boot configuration file like application.properties. After that, you can get datasource:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

DataSourceBuilder.create()
    .url(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"))
    .driverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"))
    .username(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"))
    .password(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"))
    .build());
```

Then use the datasource to get SqlSession:

```
    TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
    Environment environment = new Environment("id", transactionFactory, "id");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
    configuration.addMapper(YourMapper.class);

    return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(configuration));
```

Then use SqlSession get mapper:

```
sqlSession.getMapper(YourMapper.class);
```

Mybatis just needs a SqlSession to getMapper and run mapping, exposing mapping with a Java interface. So mybatis doesn't need to pay attention on datasource.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP specifically asks about datasource configuration in `mybatis-config.xml`

Comment: Declaring datasource in mybatis configuration file. Using the declared datasource in the application is what the requirement. This answer doesnot speaks on that. @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

Mybatis machinery requires `DataSource` to create jdbc `Connection` that it can use to execute queries. In a regular setup that uses mybatis-spring this `DataSource` is configured as a bean in the spring context. Mappers are also beans in the spring context that use that datasource (indirectly via `SqlSession`).

You can configure the `DataSource` in `mybatis-config.xml` as described in the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html). The only problem is that in that case spring will not be aware of this `DataSource`, it will not be a bean in the spring context. And that's the problem that you face.

Spring will not manage transactions for you in this case, you will not be able to inject mappers or `SqlSession` in your beans. Basically you will lose everything what mybatis-spring integration gives you so it makes very little (if any at all) sense to configure mybatis `DataSource` in mybatis config.

If you nevertheless do that you would need to [manually](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html#Building_SqlSessionFactory_from_XML) create `SqlSession` from the xml configuration and then manually commit/rollback transaction via `SqlSession.commit`/`SqlSession.rollback`.